# ¿Cómo hacer una resta hasta llegar a cero en PHP?

Tags: php, algoritmos, contador

¿Cómo puedo hacer para tener *un elemento capturado A* y *uno predefinido B*?

```
A=3000 // Capturado por el usuario
B=500 // Predefinido
```

Desearía saber en `PHP` cómo saber cuántas veces puedo poner `A` en `B` y si sale negativo igualar a cero.

He intentado con ciclos pero no me sale:

```
while ($resultado > 0) {

    $resultado=4000-$valoringresadoppp;

    if ($resultado>0 ) {
        # code...
    } else {
        # code...
    }

    if($resultado > 0){
        echo '//El número es positivo.';
        echo "<br>";
    }else if($resultado < 0){
        echo '//El número es negativo.';
        $resultado=$resultado*-1;
        echo $resultado;
        echo "<br>";
    }else{
        echo '///El número es cero.';
    }

echo $resultado++;
echo "<br>";
```

Comment: En tu `while` asignas `$resultado=4000-$valoringresadoppp;`lo cual siempre da lo mismo por lo que o solo se ejecutará una vez o será infinito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la condición `while` lo que estás haciendo es verificar que mientras el resultado sea mayor a cero ejecute el código y ahí realizas la resta, pero en cada pasada del `while` vuelves a asignarle `4000`, por ende entra en un ciclo infinito. Algo también que me llamó la atención es que vuelves a verificar si el resultado es mayor a cero fuera del `while`, armé la variable `$resultado` asignándole `4000` pero puedes asignarle el valor que quieras.

```
$resultado = 4000

while ($resultado > 0) {
    // Va a verificar mientras $resultado sea mayor a cero si es menor a cero
    // Sale del ciclo
    // En i++ vas a almacenar la cantidad de veces que realizó la operación

    $resultado= $resultado -$valoringresadoppp;
    i++
}
if($resultado > 0){
    echo '//El número es positivo.';
    echo "<br>";
}else if($resultado < 0){
    echo '//El número es negativo.';
    $resultado=$resultado*-1;
    echo $resultado;
    echo "<br>";
}else{
    echo '///El número es cero.';
}
echo $resultado++;
echo "<br>";
```

Luego, lo que tendrías que hacer es mostrar `i++` que contiene la cantidad de veces que realizó el ciclo `while`, lo cual es lo mismo a la cantidad de veces que entra `A` en `B`.